# How can I verify the speed of my NIC in ubuntu?

Tags: nic

Is there a command that I can verify by its output the speed of my **NIC** and some information about its characteristics such as duplex full or half .

Answer (score 60):

Suppose your NIC name `eth0` :

You can verify the speed and some informations by three **Commands** :

**First Command :**

```
dmesg |grep eth0
```

Output :

[image]

**Second Command :**

```
mii-tool -v  eth0
```

Output :

[image]

FD : full duplex ,  Logic that enables concurrent sending and receiving. This is usually desirable and enabled when your computer is connected to a switch.

HD : half duplex , his logic requires a card to only send or receive at a single point of time. When your machine is connected to a Hub, it auto-negotiates itself and uses half duplex to avoid collisions.

**Third command :**

```
ethtool eth0

ethtool - Display or change ethernet card settings
```

Install ethtool :

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
```

Output :

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: ethtool eth0 is installed on 18.04 by default

Comment: @RyanJeremiahFreeman only if you don't chose the minimal install option, my 18.04 did not have that installed by default

Answer (score 25):

To obtain the link speed of an interface without parsing logs or installing additional tools, simply read its corresponding speed sysfs node, as follows:

```
cat /sys/class/net/<interface>/speed
```

where  is the name of your NIC, e.g. eth0

Comment: On 19.04, I had to get the name of eth0, obtained from dmesg. In my case, eth0 has been renamed enp0s31f6. So the command to get the speed was cat /sys/class/net/enp0s31f6/speed This information was also available through the GUI, through the network icon of the top bar : Wired Connected > Wired Settings

Comment: An extremely elegant solution, and very script-friendly. It retrieves the information directly from the source.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use **NetSpeed Extension**

NetSpeed is a GNOME shell extension that displays the sum of your download and upload speed in your gnome panel. Clicking on it displays the separate values in a drop-down.

You can download it from Ubuntu Software Store.

It is applicable only if you use the GNOME desktop environment.

*Reference*: https://itsfoss.com/network-speed-monitor-linux/

Comment: Why is this the top answer? It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @KeeleyHoek

Comment: I read the question to ask how to check statistics of the underlying Ethernet connection, let (e.g. 1Gbps), and whether it is full or half duplex, etc, not what its current actual utilization is. Sorry, what I wrote sounds a bit aggressive in retrospect.

Comment: Ohh, you are right @KeeleyHoek. But when I was serching to check my NIC speed, I came to this thread, beacuse of the nature of the title. So, I thought many like me would be directed here by google search for the same. Hence, I posted my answer. I hope that this will help someone. And never mind about aggressiveness. Text is the best way to create misunderstanding.