# How to get network usage in percentage

Tags: network-monitoring

I am able to get current upload and download rate, but how do I get the max upload and download rates for the network interface I am using, in *nix systems?

For example, Windows shows network usage in percent, as shown below:

[image]

EDIT: In other words, as one of the answers mentioned that Windows shows the **utilization of my network hardware**. I would like to know the same in Linux, how do I do it?

This will be very useful to know if my network adapter is causing the bottleneck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which application can I use for a network traffic monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307318/which-application-can-i-use-for-a-network-traffic-monitor)

Comment: In [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307318/which-application-can-i-use-for-a-network-traffic-monitor) question, the OP is only looking for a way to find current down/upload rate and total traffic. I need the utilization of the network hardware

Comment: Windows doesn't show that neither: Just the higher level utilization, so that duplicate is an answer to your original question..

Answer (score 1):

Windows calculates network usage as a percentage of the link speed of your internet connection (like 45 or 150Mbps). This simply measures the utilization of your network hardware and is **not a measure of available bandwidth**. Hence not a good method to check if network is the bottleneck in your scenario.

However, if this is exactly what you want, find out the link speed as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/431912/796752). (change `eth0` to appropriate interface)

```
dmesg | grep eth0
```

Using this value and your current speeds, you can estimate the network utilization.
Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to get it. I tried `dmesg | grep enp6s0`, is it a 18.04 thing?

Comment: I would like to know how to find the utilization of the network hardware

Answer (score 1):

To check your link speed you can run `lshw -C Network`

```
lshw -C Network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: internet0
       serial: b8:27:eb:6f:c7:75
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=smsc95xx driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=full firmware=smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.178.56 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

To check the actual up and download usage i use `bmon`

[image]